# This project was scheduled for deletion, but failed with the following message: Failed to open TCP connection to <host>:5000

Tags: gitlab, port

The project has this message:

> This project was scheduled for deletion, but failed with the following
> message: Failed to open TCP connection to host.ru:5000 (Connection
> refused - connect(2) for "host.ru" port 5000)

Can you tell me what this might be related to? Why does gitlab use a different port for deletion ?

(default port is 30443)

How do I delete this message?
A lot of questions, but I really don't understand what this message is. clearly this is an error :)

Gitlab is located in docker.

[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi8go.png)

P.S. Now I check whether the port is open.

UP! If you don't need the container register, then disable it. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue:

gitlab is running in a separate docker container and registry is running in a separate docker container. gitlab container is not able to resolve the dns name for the registry and gives the error

"this project was scheduled for deletion, but failed with the following message: failed to open tcp connection to registry:5000 (getaddrinfo: name or service not known)"

Solution:

1. docker inspect (registry container name)

   E.g. docker inspect registry
2. get the IP address of the registry container
3. Login to gitlab container machine :

   E.g. docker exec -it gitlab bash
4. Edit the hosts file

   vi /etc/hosts
5. Add the ip address and dns name mapping for the runner container
   in the hostfile

   172.xx.x.1      registry

This will resolve this issue.
no restarts required.

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer! on my server, the register is located in the same container with gitlab